# How many provisoning profiles we can create according to a single App Id?

Tags: iphone

How many we can create provisioning profiles onto a single App Id?
I've one more question is that, Is APNS need developer provision profiles instead of Distribution, because i am facing error in command but it successfully install onto device and i've Distribution profile of adhoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it should work: App Id with Push for both environments. You can use any distribution profile should work as long as it is assigned to that app id and re downloaded from the portal